# StopIteration exception raised in a function

Tags: python, stopiteration

I have the following function in my python script:

```
def subset_sum (list_of_int,target):
    #create iterable
    itr = chain.from_iterable(combinations(list_of_int, n) for n in range(2,len(list_of_int)-1))
    #number of iteration rounds
    rounds = 1000000
    i = cycle(itr)
    #instantiate a list where iterations based on number of rounds will be stored
    list_of_iteration = []
    #loop to create a list of the first n rounds
    for x in range(rounds):
        list_of_iteration.append(next(i)) 
    #find the first list item that = target 
    for y in list_of_iteration:
        if sum(y) == target: 
            return list(y)
```

My question is why am I getting a StopIteration error?
When I test this formula in a small data set it works fine without any issues.
However, when I apply it to the larger dataset the exception comes up.

It says that the issue is in line `list_of_iteration.append(next(i))`

What am I doing wrong?

these is the stack trace:

```
 File "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", line 19, in subset_sum
    list_of_iteration.append(next(i))

StopIteration
```

KeyboardInterrupt

Comment: Please **always** provide a [mcve] for questions seeking debugging help. If you are getting an error, post the *full error message including the stack trace*. The Python runtime goes to great lengths to provide you with that, why would you just omit it?

Answer (score 1):

The variable "itr" must be empty.  If you try to next() a cycle() on an empty iterator you get a StopIteration.  Try this:

```
empty = []
i = cycle(empty)
print(next(i))
```

Comment: probably true, but please do not answer questions that don't follow the basic guidelines

Answer (score 0):

The `StopIteration` error is an exception that is thrown from the
`next` method when there is no next element in the iterator that
`next` is called on.

In your code, the iterator `i` must have fewer elements than
required by the value of `rounds`.